Are the famous operators S_n of Fourier series theory continuous?
In a previous Q&A of mine (this here) I mentioned what Katznelson calls homogeneous Banach spaces on the torus $\mathbb T = \mathbb R / 2\pi \mathbb Z $ (I mention him here because others define the expresssion in italics completely differently and without reference to a base space - like the torus - and probably without any relationship to his def. except that both mention Banach spaces). In that older Q&A I give his definition and it was settled that for each such space $B$ there is a linear operator $S_n:B \rightarrow B$ because $f \in B \implies S_n(f) \in B$ where $S_n(f)$ has the usual meaning in Fourier series theory (see there too for this). For a more precise notation I'll call this operator $S_{n,B}$. BTW $L^1(\mathbb T)$ is itself such a space for its standard norm (easily verified).
The question is now: is $S_{n,B}$ continuous (in the $B$-norm), in other words bounded - this in general or specifically for $B=L^1(\mathbb T)$? In case the answer for this spec. case is no, can you prove it? If the answer is yes in this case, but no in general, can you give a simple counter-example for the used $B$? If it is yes in general, I'd like to get a hint for the proof.
Motivation: I have intuitively conjectured a no at least for a general $B$, in which case I imagine that the norm of an unbounded lin. operator were supposed to be defined as being $\infty$. Then I came into trouble with the theorem in section 1.1. of chapt.2 of Katznelson's Introduction to Harmonic Analysis, where he uses in his proof the uniform boundedness principle - a weird name btw because probably very few dictionaries contain even the word boundedness (because of this the French wikipedia hasn't an equivalent!) - and it is often not clear which result is referred to by this name. (That given in wikipedia seems to be a good guess, for the context where I need it as well as one might expect that it is more or less the dominant choice.) So before I address this difficulty, I prefer to settle first the question I am asking here.
Now while looking for the exact reference to Katznelson's book, I realize that he gives an implicit answer to my question after his proof. Except for a still possible misunderstanding, the answer would be: yes in general. But he uses there an inequality without further explanation concerning the $B$-norm, needing more insight.

The continuity of $S_n$ should result from the triangle inequality: if $f\in B$, then
$$|S_n(f)|_B=|D_n*f|B=\left|\frac 1{2\pi}\int{\mathbb T}D_n(t)f_t,dt\right|B\leq\frac 1{2\pi}\int{\mathbb T}|D_n(t)||f_t|B,dt=|D_n|{L^1(\mathbb T)}|f|_B.$$
And also, the uniform boundedness principle is better known in French as the théorème de Banach-Steinhaus, named after the authors of this paper where the result appeared seemingly for the first time.

Thanks. Yes that was the idea, to use again the integral and then what you call "triangle inequality" (continuous analog of the tr. ineq. with finite sums itself resulting from the def. of a norm where the sum has 2 terms). In the last step you use one of the "axioms" of homogeneous B. spaces - so we prove what I call the inequality without further explanation in the book which proves continuity of $S_{n,B}$

To what concerns the unif. bound. princ.: I know that but the problem is the same with the name "theorem of Banach-Steinhaus" and its wordly translation to F; even in wikipedia, comparing en- and fr- versions you have some difference ...
